# Special observations

Tags: word, knowledge

**What's missing? The answer to that is a 6-letter word. Can you figure out what that word is?**

---

- Arkansas river, USA
- Bahrain Island, Bahrain
- Akimiski Island, Canada
- Mountain ranges, Southeastern Tibet
- Pinaki Island, French Polynesia
- Rivers, southeastern Kyrgyzstan
- Trunk reef, Australia
- Sirmilik National Park Pond Inlet, Canada
- Snow, north eastern USA
- Tian Shan mountains, northeastern Kyrgyzstan
- Ship tracks over the Pacific
- Mackenzie River Delta, Canada
- Lonar Crater, India
- Lago Menendez, Argentina
- Clouds swirling over the Atlantic Ocean.
- Development along two roads, United Arab Emirates.
- Ash on the snow around Shiveluch, Russia
- Dust blowing over the Red Sea
- Northwest corner of Leidy Glacier, Greenland.
- Ugab River, Namibia.
- Wildfire smoke, Canada.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The missing word is

> VOWELS

Explanation:

> The bullet points describe images in the [ABCs from space](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/ABC) as published by the NASA Earth Observatory. This is a set of images taken from space that look like letters of the alphabet.

> The following images are missing:
>  1. **Green River, USA** [image: A riverbend that looks like a lowercase "a"]
>  2. **Phytoplankton, New Zealand** [image: Swirls of phytoplankton in the shape of a lowercase "e"]
>  3. **Andaman Islands, India** [image: A tall and a small island arranged like a lowercase "i"]
>  4. **Tenoumer Crater, Mauritania** [image: A nearly circular crater looking like an "o".]
>  5. **River in Gooseneck State Park, Utah** [image: A riverbend in the shape of a "u"]

> They represent the letters A,E,I,O,U or, in one 6-letter word, the **"vowels"**.

Comment: I realise you pipped me to the post by 4 minutes, but I figured that I had some slightly different content in my answer (re the solving process and the identities of all items in the list) that would be worth posting anyway as a complementary answer to yours. Well done :)

Comment: That's indeed the 6-letter word I was looking for. Great job!

Answer (score 10):

I'm pretty sure the word here is:

> **VOWELS**

Because what I originally suspected the OP had done here is...

> ...scour satellite images - probably on Google Maps/Earth - to find natural **formations that resemble consonants of the English alphabet**.
>
>  I then set about searching Google Maps for many of these and found some immediately (e.g. Akimiski Island (pictured below) is a clear 'D' shape, Pinaki Island makes an excellent 'G', Trunk Reef is clearly a lower-case 'j', Lago Menendez makes a lower-case 'r', and there's a great 'X' in the view of Leidy Glacier).
>
>  [image: Akimiski Island, in the shape of a letter 'D']
>
>  However, some of them were going to be particularly hard to pinpoint exactly - anyone who could identify from 'Clouds swirling over the Atlantic Ocean' the exact S-shaped cloud formation from more than 100 million square kilometres of photographed ocean deserves a medal of some kind... And it was when searching Google for terms like 'the letter B in the Arkansas River' that I stumbled upon [this website](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/ABC), in which somebody from NASA has made a list of this exact concept! And - wouldn't you know it - the OP has used many of the same items!

From this list, we get:

> Arkansas river, USA = **b**
>  Bahrain Island, Bahrain = **C**
>  Akimiski Island, Canada = **D**
>  Mountain ranges, Southeastern Tibet = **F**
>  Pinaki Island, French Polynesia = **G**
>  Rivers, southeastern Kyrgyzstan = **H**
>  Trunk reef, Australia = **j**
>  Sirmilik National Park Pond Inlet, Canada = **K** (the glaciers within it)
>  Snow, north eastern USA = **L**
>  Tian Shan mountains, northeastern Kyrgyzstan = **m**
>  Ship tracks over the Pacific = **N**
>  Mackenzie River Delta, Canada = **P**
>  Lonar Crater, India = **Q**
>  Lago Menendez, Argentina = **r**
>  Clouds swirling over the Atlantic Ocean = **S**
>  Development along two roads, United Arab Emirates = **T**
>  Ash on the snow around Shiveluch, Russia = **V**
>  Dust blowing over the Red Sea = **w**
>  Northwest corner of Leidy Glacier, Greenland = **X**
>  Ugab River, Namibia = **Y**
>  Wildfire smoke, Canada = **Z**

All of which means that we are missing...

> ...the items from this list which represent the English **VOWELS** - our missing 6-letter word.

Comment: Great job! I'm giving the tick to @xyldke since he/she answered a couple of minutes earlier  than you, with the same anwer, but well done anyways!

Comment: @Prim3numbah Not a problem - theirs is a good and correct answer and they got there before me :)